# Amazon SES Soft Bounce

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

When a soft bounce event happens how long does SES retries to deliver the email. Here [amazon SES email](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-email-with-ses.html) it says " Amazon SES retries sending the email for a length of time", didn't specify the exact time though.

Answer (score 5):

A similar question was asked long back on the Amazon Forum, the answer available there is :

> When attempting to deliver an email, Amazon SES will continue making delivery attempts until receiving a successful response, or until 12 hours elapse. If the receiving ISP returns a temporary error code (e.g., a 4xx SMTP code), then SES will keep trying. There is no limit to the number of attempts; however, SES will apply exponential backoff between retries for up to 12 hours.

You can check the [post here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=110939)

Comment: I also found this old (maybe outdated) AWS blog from 2012-06-05 saying "Unlike a hard bounce, a soft bounce is not a permanent failure or rejection (e.g., mailbox full). Many email systems (including Amazon SES) will automatically try to resend a message that has generated a soft bounce over a period of time until the message either delivers or the system will no longer retry the delivery and in turn generates a hard bounce."  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/email-definitions-bounces/

Comment: And https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/aws-amazon-ses-best-practices.pdf from 2012-07 says " Amazon SES handles soft bounces automatically by retrying with optimal settings for the domain you’re sending to." I wish they were more specific.

Comment: https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-ses-developer-guide/blob/ec08804/doc-source/sending-concepts-deliverability.md from 2019-09-06 says "Soft bounce – A temporary email delivery failure. For example, the mailbox is full, there are too many connections (also called throttling), or the connection times out. Amazon SES retries soft bounces multiple times. If the email still cannot be delivered, then Amazon SES stops retrying it. Amazon SES notifies you of hard bounces and soft bounces that will no longer be retried. However, only hard bounces count toward your bounce rate and the bounce metric..."

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Support say it's up to 840 minutes:

> When attempting to deliver an email, Amazon SES will continue making delivery attempts until receiving a successful response, or until 840 minutes (14 hours) elapse.

For some of the emails we sent, it actually took between 15 and 16 hours before we got a "transient bounce, general" notification.

Amazon Support sort of explain this as well:

> SES will apply exponential back-off between retries for up to 840 minutes.

It's unclear if this means (a) the total time or (b) the biggest retry interval in the exponential sequence (will update if we learn more). Either way it sounds like the actual delay may exceed 840 minutes, possibly depending on other factors e.g. email server delays.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon will not disclose this information as it depends on many factors.

Answer (score 0):

You can see it in the last HARD bounce when email expires.
It's 840 minutes(14 hours).